# Import a class and use it to another file

Tags: python, class

I have 3 file. The find_threshold_l.py, simplelogicbuffer_l.py and test_find_threshold_l.py.

I need to import the first two files into the last one.

This is the class in the simplelogicbuffer_l.py file:

```
class SimpleLogicBuffer:

    def __init__(self, on_threshold):
        self.on_threshold = on_threshold
        self.output_state = False

    def apply_input_voltage(self, value):
        self.output_state = value > self.on_threshold

    def is_on(self):
        return self.output_state
```

Here's the code in the find_threshold_l.py file:

```
from simplelogicbuffer_l import SimpleLogicBuffer

def find_threshold(input_value, output_state):

    if output_state == True:
        while output_state == True:
            input_value -= 10
            if input_value > SimpleLogicBuffer.DUT_Logic_Buffer.on_threshold:
                continue
            else:
                SimpleLogicBuffer.DUT_Logic_Buffer.output_state = False
                input_value
                return input_value / 1000
                break
    else:
        while output_state == False:
            input_value += 10
            if input_value <= SimpleLogicBuffer.DUT_Logic_Buffer.on_threshold:
                continue
            else:
                SimpleLogicBuffer.DUT_Logic_Buffer.output_state = True
                input_value -= 10
                return input_value / 1000
                break
```

Here's what I wrote in the last file:

```
from simplelogicbuffer_l import SimpleLogicBuffer
from find_threshold_l import find_threshold

DUT_Logic_Buffer = SimpleLogicBuffer(12500)

print("The threshold voltage is {}V".format(find_threshold(11000, DUT_Logic_Buffer.is_on())))
```

But when I run this code, there's a error.

It said: `AttributeError: type object 'SimpleLogicBuffer' has no attribute 'DUT_Logic_Buffer'`

I'm a little confused. Is there something to do with the `print` function call or other reason?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you importing the modules with `_l`?

Comment: That error is strange, but it's impossible to know what's going on without seeing more code, `find_threshold` in particular. Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce this error.

Comment: @Coldspeed My mistake. The file name contain this " _l" as well.

Comment: There's no `some_object.DUT_Logic_Buffer_1` in this code, so the error must be occuring somewhere else.

Comment: @PM2Ring Got it. I just updated the question with the code for the function.

Answer (score 0):

This will throw an error because your `DUT_Logic_Buffer_1` is only available to you in `test_find_threshold_l`, and your `SimpleLogicBuffer` does't have any attribute `DUT_Logic_Buffer_1`. You can solve this error by pass ing the value in the function `find_threshold` directly instead of `SimpleLogicBuffer.DUT_Logic_Buffer_1.on_threshold`, or you can do directly as: `SimpleLogicBuffer(some_value).on_threshold`

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway I can initialize the DUT_Logic_Buffer_1 in the test_find_threshold.py file?

Comment: Pass the instance in as an argument.